# How to define function inside knockout viewmodel that is filled with Json data

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I am having issues with defining a function inside my viewmodel.

I fetch json data via jquery getJSON and map this data to my viewmodel.

```
$.getJSON('/Company/GetCompanies', function(data) { 
    var viewModel = new CompanyViewModel()
    viewModel.model = ko.mapping.fromJS(data)
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel)
});
```

Below is my viewmodel. As you can see what I want to do is, returning one of the properties of viewmodel via function called `companyName`

```
var CompanyViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;

    self.companyName = function()
         return model.CompanyName; 
    };
}
```

Then I want to use this function like `<span data-bind="text: companyName" />` However, the JavaScript function is not evaluated and returned as text.

I go through the examples of Knockout on the web, but all of them are using computed observables.

Is there a way to achive this ? Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you want to use a computed observable?

Comment: I can use of course but I don't need companyName to be observed. I am wondering what is the issue with my code

Comment: It shouldn't be `return self.CompanyName;` ?

Comment: return statement might be wrong, but return 'text'; is not even working.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
var CompanyViewModel = function(data) {
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, this); 
};

CompanyViewModel.prototype.fileTaxes = function() {
    console.log("Company is filing taxes.");
};

$.getJSON('/Company/GetCompanies', function(data) { 

    // data would look something like this: 
    // data: { companyName : "MicroStrategy",
    //         founderName : "etc" }
    var viewModel = new CompanyViewModel(data);
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel)
});
```

Comment: where is the company function ? I am trying to define a function inside viewmodel.

Comment: I've edited the original code to include an example of adding a method to the class CompanyViewModel (it's called fileTaxes). You don't need to create the companyName function anymore, as it is handled by the ko.mapping.fromJS function.

Answer (score 1):

I've made some test, and this works for me:

`return self.model()[0].CompanyName;`

And call it with: `data-bind="text: companyName()"`

**EDIT:**

```
       var CompanyViewModel = function() {
            var self = this;

            self.companyName = function(){

                 return self.model()[0].CompanyName; 
            };
        }

        $.getJSON('/Company/GetCompanies', function(data) { 
            var viewModel = new CompanyViewModel();
            viewModel.model = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
            ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
        });
```

This works assuming that your JSON data is returned in a format like:

```
[{"CompanyName":"Stack","SomeOtherField":"SomeOtherValue"},...];
```

and that you have only one company inside it.